# when object will be eligible for garbage collecion

Tags: java, garbage-collection

A method given to me and asked, when it will be eligible for Garbage Collection, i mean at which line. I believe both `o` and `oa` are eligible for garbage collection. Since, they are set to `null`. Please correct me, if i'm wrong. But, the question was, when it will be eligible for `gc`, i mean at which line. ?

```
public Object m() {
        Object o = new Float(3.14F);
        Object[] oa = new Object[1];
        oa[0] = o; /* Line 5 */
        o = null; /* Line 6 */
        oa[0] = null; /* Line 7 */
        return o; /* Line 8 */
    }
```

Please anyone explain. ?

Comment: What line do you think it is?

Comment: i believe, it would be.. line 5 ??

Comment: haha @ Woot4Moo ... that scene in 40 yr old virgin, where he answers all her questions with questions..

Comment: @speakingcode like a bag of sand.

Comment: Why do you think it would be line 5?

Comment: A good enough compiler could replace the whole function body with "return null;". The objects need never be allocated, let alone GC'd.

Comment: @AlanStokes sure, but if he had an `if` block in there I don't think the same would be true.

Comment: @Woot Yes, but that would be a different question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo because.. `ao[0]` refers to `null`. correct me..

Comment: well `oa[0] = o` is line 5.  So no.  Please see my answer for a bit of an explanation.

Comment: @AlanStokes: actually no, a Java compiler is not allowed to do that (because it can not know what kind of side effects object creation does). The *JVM* on the other hand, *could* make that optimization, but I doubt it does.

Comment: @Joachim why do you think I meant javac rather than a JIT compiler? I'd be surprised if Hotspot et al. didn't inline this function to nothing.

Comment: @AlanStokes: sorry if I assumed, many people think `javac` can do/does all kinds of optimizations when it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us walk through the code:

```
1)  o = new Float();  
2)  oa = new Object[];  
    at this point we have 2 objects.  
3) oa[0] = o;  
    at this point oa[0] holds the reference of o.  
4)  o = null;  
    o is still being referenced by oa[0]  
5)  oa[0] = null  
    o now has zero references.  
6)  return o;  
     o is null.
```

Line 7 is where the GC eligibility happens for `o`.  `oa` is not eligible for GC until the function exits.

In general, an object is only eligible for GC when there are no references left to it.  Be very careful when dealing with a `String` as there is a special place called the String pool.  So the following code:

```
void foo()  
{  
   String s = "foo";   
   s=null;  
   return s;  
}
```

At no point is `s` guaranteed to be eligible in the function.

**Question from comments**

> one question, you said..oa is not eligible for GC until the function
>   exits. but, before the return o, oa set to be null and it nowhere
>   referred too

Answer:

> oa is not set to null. What gets set to null is the object at oa[0]
>   (the first index of oa). If the line was oa = null that would be true,
>   and irrespective of the only item in oa being null, does not in fact
>   make the wrapper (in this case an array) null. Similar to having a
>   List and nulling out all of its elements does not make the List null.

Comment: i have one question, you said..`oa` is not eligible for GC until the function exits. but, before the `return o`, `oa` set to be `null` and it nowhere referred too.

Comment: `oa` is not set to null.  What gets set to null is the object at `oa[0]` (the first index of `oa`).   If the line was `oa = null` that would be true, and irrespective of the only item in `oa` being null, does not in fact make the wrapper (in this case an array) null.  Similar to having a `List` and nulling out all of its elements does not make the `List` null.

Answer (score 3):

Java is allowed to do certain optimizations, so an optimizing JIT that reasons only about local-effects could simplify this code to

```
public Object m() {
    //Object o =                    // o does not participate in any externally visible side-effect
    new Float(3.14F);               // Available for collection as soon as ctor finishes.
    //Object[] oa = new Object[1];  // Array ctors are known not to have side-effects, and oa does not participate in a side-effect or result that is visible outside the method.
    //oa[0] = o; /* Line 5 */       // Side-effect not visible.
    // o = null; /* Line 6 */       // Side-effect not visible.
    //oa[0] = null; /* Line 7 */
    //return o; /* Line 8 */        // Eliminated by inlining.
    return null;                    // Type-analysis proves that this method can only return null.
}
```

Don't assume that assignments of local variables to `null` actually happen in long-lived method calls.

Comment: i dont know how much this answers OP's question.  however fun code sample.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, I edited to include "Don't assume ..." so I think the answer is that the question is based on a flawed premise.  There is no guarantee that the array will actually be allocated or that either object will be marked by virtue of being part of a live stack frame, or that an assignment to `null` will happen and thus prevent an object from being marked live by virtue of being part of a live stack frame.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is *eligible* when no reference to that object exists any longer, but it can be important to note that GC is not guaranteed to run at that time, so technically the memory can be allocated.

oa[0] refers to the object, so when you set it to null at line 7, no reference to that object exists any longer, so it is eligible for GC.

As pointed out on comments, oa, the array itself, is still around until the method is done executing, i.e. after line 8 executes. It is local to the lifetime of the method m(), so it will be eligible for GC when m() returns from execution.

Comment: Best answer so far but OP also asked about `oa`. Since `oa` is a local variable and its value is never set `null` during the method it is eligible after the method is done (removed from stack).

Answer (score 0):

> Please correct me, if i'm wrong. But, the question was, when it will be eligible for gc, i mean at which line. ?

The question is nonsensical or based upon an over-simplified model of garbage collection. Garbage collectors act at run-time on the available representation which means tracing reachability from global roots including the registers, stack and global variables. There is no correspondance with high-level source code so it does not make sense to ask about line numbers. In reality, the compiler will mangle your code beyond all recognition before the GC runs.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, Java uses the Mark-And-Sweep algorithm. The GC runs in a separate thread over the heap repeatedly.

If a certain reference variable(or object) goes out of scope, its marked for deletion and sweeped off when appropriate(or overwritten).

Also whenever the variable is set to null, that is when the <s>reference count</s> object becomes *unreachable* by static references and other threads, that is when its reference no longer exists, its marked for deletion again.

Line7 in your code is where it will be marked for deletion.

Comment: GC algorithm can be configurable.

Comment: Where do reference counts enter into this?  None of the standard Java GCs use reference counts.